# List, display form, change link

Tags: tasks

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to get my project "dashboard" to work.

Currently i´ve got one list for my projects, one list for all project tasks and one site page with presentation about the project, project information and its tasks.

What im trying to accomplish is when the projectname is clicked my new site page containing information about the selected project and its tasks is loaded.

Now its opening the view form dialog. 
I dont want to replace all functionality such as edit dialog or view dialog in dropdown menu just change the project name link.

Hope you can help me with this!

Thanks!

//Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom action on your list either via SharePoint designer (simplest - not too much control), see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500259.aspx#odc_sp14_ta_AddCustomActiontoDisplay_CreatingCustomActionSharePointDesigner

or more complex, but full control http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/joe_ferner/how_to_add_a_custom_action_to.html

This should offer the opportunity to call in directly to that action!

Comment: Thanks for your response C. Marius. 

I was looking for a solution where the project name link is pointing to my custom dashboard page, not a new custom action in the dropdown. 

Tried and adding a new custom action but its not quite what is was looking for.

Comment: Then you should opt simply for re-creating a new Display Form and mark it as the default View Form. This way automatically users will be redirected on that.

Comment: Okay, seems as a winner. 
Is it possible to add a parameter value to the url for filtering the task list or is it better to try and append it using javascript?

Comment: Because you are building your own form, you can add any web parts, such as QueryStringFilter, etc. that shall filter other Web Parts.